# Does a pinch imply the presence of memcomponents?

Tags: hysteresis, memristor

There is a famous article by Chua ["If it's pinched it's a memristor"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0268-1242/29/10/104001), where he defines a memristor as having a "[...] pinched hysteresis loop in the voltage–current plane when driven by any periodic voltage[...]", in particular he states the pinch must be at V=0. The problem I have is that I'm characterizing a component which has a pinched hysteresis loop like this for example [image], where the pinch is not at zero (in the article he calls this an imperfect memristor). In my system the pinch also disappears with different driving frequencies

[image]

What I want to know is if the presence of the pinch is enough to know that there are mem-components in my system. I know for sure it's not only a memristor because it has a capacitance for example. Is is possible to get a pinched hysteresis loop without memcomponents ever?

Comment: Found an article which might address this question, http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2018/1747865.pdf